# I have two Windows OSs, but no option for dual boot (OSs on SSD and HDD)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I bought new MBO and CPU, and before that I had Windows 8 installed on one of my HDDs. When I set everything up, I managed to boot into my Windows 8.

I also bought an SSD drive, and I installed Windows 7 on it.

However, I don't have an option to dual boot. It just boots Windows 7 from my SSD.

I tried to fix it with EasyBCD, but the software recognizes Windows 7 bootloader only.

BIOS is set to boot Legacy+UEFI.

Comment: The simply solution would be to repair the Windows 8 bootloader then modify the boot options with EasyBCD.  You could also use grub and configure all by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bootloader on either drive, and the SSD is set as the first boot device. I'd probably simply select which drive is the primary boot drive from the bios, its the simplest, cleanest option.